# Strange number when using fmt.Println in Golang

Tags: json, go, substring

I'm new to Golang and have been doing alright but I have a strange issue that I have not encountered before when using fmt. This strange behavior is when I'm printing a string. At the end of the string (which has sub-strings) it is also printing out what appears to be the len() of each string although the number don't add up. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to stop it?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"log"
    "strings"
)

var e = "[{8888a8558921d75ec8bc362efbe9a76b82ec002337534e9f06ce92cbf8c27c8888 localhost:3303 4d50f447-7c93-42df-a03e-89c09626950a}]"



func main() {
    tl := strings.Trim(e, "[{")
    tr := strings.Trim(tl, "}]")
    r := strings.TrimSpace(tr)
    s := strings.Fields(r)
    
    V_PK := s[0]
    SERVER_ADDR := s[1]
    A_KEY := s[2]

    vv, _ := fmt.Printf("[{\"v_pk\": %q", V_PK)
    pp, _ := fmt.Printf(",\"server_addr\": %q", SERVER_ADDR)
    kk, _ := fmt.Printf(",\"a_key\": %q}] ", A_KEY)
    rstr, _ := fmt.Println(vv, pp, kk)
    stringc := string(rstr)
    
    fmt.Println(stringc)

    
}
```

Expected output:

```
[{"v_pk": "8888a8558921d75ec8bc362efbe9a76b82ec002337534e9f06ce92cbf8c27c8888","server_addr": "localhost:3303","a_key": "4d50f447-7c93-42df-a03e-89c09626950a"}]
```

Actual output:

```
[{"v_pk": "8888a8558921d75ec8bc362efbe9a76b82ec002337534e9f06ce92cbf8c27c8888","server_addr": "localhost:3303","a_key": "4d50f447-7c93-42df-a03e-89c09626950a"}] 82 36 53
```

Why on earth would it be printing these string lengths on the end? It's probably obvious that I'm trying to build a JSON string so these numbers on the end are problematic when trying to import the string into a JSON interpreter.

Again, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation for `fmt.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) and its friends `fmt.Println`. The documentation reads:

> Printf formats according to a format specifier and **writes to standard output**. It **returns the number of bytes written** and any write error encountered.

The line in your code

```
vv, _ := fmt.Printf("[{\"v_pk\": %q", V_PK)
```

prints the formatted string to standard output, then return the number of bytes written and stores that in `vv`. If you want to print the formatted string to standard output, just call `fmt.Printf` and ignore the output:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"log"
    "strings"
)

var e = "[{8888a8558921d75ec8bc362efbe9a76b82ec002337534e9f06ce92cbf8c27c8888 localhost:3303 4d50f447-7c93-42df-a03e-89c09626950a}]"

func main() {
    tl := strings.Trim(e, "[{")
    tr := strings.Trim(tl, "}]")
    r := strings.TrimSpace(tr)
    s := strings.Fields(r)

    V_PK := s[0]
    SERVER_ADDR := s[1]
    A_KEY := s[2]

    fmt.Printf("[{\"v_pk\": %q, \"server_addr\": %q, \"a_key\": %q}]\n", V_PK, SERVER_ADDR, A_KEY)
}
```

Or, if you want to store the formatted string to a new string variable, call [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf):

```
stringc := fmt.Sprintf("[{\"v_pk\": %q, \"server_addr\": %q, \"a_key\": %q}]", V_PK, SERVER_ADDR, A_KEY)
fmt.Println(stringc)
```

You can check out a working version [at the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/1dL0o3iL8s7)

You might also want to checkout the [`json` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json), which can do the parsing and serializing for you with properly defined structs:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Datum struct {
        VPK    string `json:"v_pk"`
        Server string `json:"server_addr"`
        AKey   string `json:"a_key"`
    }
    data := []Datum{
        {VPK: "8888a8558921d75ec8bc362efbe9a76b82ec002337534e9f06ce92cbf8c27c8888",
            Server: "localhost:3303",
            AKey:   "4d50f447-7c93-42df-a03e-89c09626950a",
        }}
    json, err := json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        // deal with error
    }

    fmt.Println(string(json))
}
```

Check it out at [the go playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/irusv97n9RX)

Comment: thank you for the very quick response. I corrected my code and used Sprintf on all but my final line with Println which got me exactly what I needed. Part of my issue is that I had a struct using thte typical json.Unmarshal() but the extra characters were causing an error. I will now point the string back to a struct which should work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Printf` returns the number of bytes written. The variables `vv`, `pp`, `kk` are the number of bytes written by those three `Printf` calls, and the three numbers printed are those numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response as well, this was driving me nuts for hours